# setInterval("ga('send','event','5_seconds','read')",5000); implement this via GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We would like to implement this function via google tag manager
setInterval("ga('send','event','5_seconds','read')",5000);

Answer (score 0):

if you have added google analytics code directly on website without using GTM then you can easily send event on each 5 sec by using Custom HTML Tag in GTM

i.e create Custom HTML Tag in GTM 
and Add below you code like

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){ga('send','event','5_seconds','read')},5000);
</script>
```

that's enough

but it is not going to would when you have implemented google analytics using GTM

to achive your required goal follow below steps:

1 ) create custom HTML Tag and add below code

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){dataLayer.push({'event':'5secInterval'});},5000);
</script>
```

2) Create one trigger as custom event **5secInterval**.

3) Create new google analytics Tag  set as event and mention category , action 
and trigger on **5secInterval** custom event.

I hope this will help to get your solution